# Output stops after php while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, execution

I have the following php code:

```
echo "<div style='float:left;'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th colspan='4'>Laks beholdt</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Uke</th>";
echo "<th>&lt;3 kg</th>";
echo "<th>3-7 kg</th>";
echo "<th>&gt;7 kg</th>";
echo "<th>Totalt</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) or die(mysql_error()))
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Uke'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumSmall'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumMedium'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumLarge'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumVekt'], 1, ",",
      " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

I get the expected output from the while loop, but the end tags for my table and div -or any other output for that matter- does not show. I get no error message, and I fail to see any errors in my html. I've tried referencing the array by numbers instead of associative, but I get the same result.

I've written a hundred similar loops without error, but I'm out of ideas here :/

Comment: Do you have this up on the web somewhere we can review it?

Comment: Have you tried putting any other kind of output there, immediately after the while loop? Like just the word "test"? Does that show up?

Comment: you're dying the script execution when the loop is suppose to end...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `or die()` statement is causing it to stop execution. When `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` should be stopping the loop, it hits the `die()` instead. Since there was no error, nothing is printed from `mysql_error()`

```
echo "Before loop\n";

$x = 1;
while($foo = bar($x) or die('Died')) {
    echo $x++, "\n";
}

echo "After loop\n";

function bar($x) {
    if($x < 5) {
        return $x;
    }
    return false;
}

//outputs:
//Before loop
//1
//2
//3
//4
//Died
```

[Codepad version](http://codepad.org/vrC3YpzF)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.. was in the process of trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `die()` in the loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Uke'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumSmall'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumMedium'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumLarge'], 1,
      ",", " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:right; padding-right:10px;'>" . number_format($row['SumVekt'], 1, ",",
      " ") . " kg</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is flawed, because `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `false` when all rows have been fetched from the result set, therefore the while condition becomes `false or die(mysql_error())` which executes `die()` and kills the script.

You should not use or like that, neither should you print the error to the screen like that.

The type of error reporting you are doing should depend on whether you are on production or development, but the error checking should be performed regardless.

I advise you to strongly consider something like `PDO` with exceptions, `mysqli` or a `PHP framework` altogether. It is almost always a bad idea to use the `mysql_*() API`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `mysql` function set, it's merely deprecated. PDO, mysqli and jquery isn't the answer for every question.

Answer (score 1):

It's the or die statement.  If you want to have the loop die on an error set a custom error handler function that sets a boolean if there is an error.  Then you could do something like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) or !$error_hander)
```